# String operators C++

Tags: c++, string, compare

I was wondering if you can compare two strings using `==`. I have a function which takes in a `const value &item` and since its a `value` type there is no way I can determine what type the value is, hence if the `value` type is a `string`, `==` may not work.

Hence the question, what would be the best way to tackle this problem? I was thinking of overloading the `==` operator, but is there an easy way?

Comment: Is value a type parameter or some universal type from some library?

Comment: "since its a value type there is no way I can determine what type the value is" - do you mean that you're writing generic code, and `value` is the `value_type` of some container? If so, then there's no guarantee that it's possible to compare values of that type for equality. `string` you can, but there's no requirement that types stored in containers must be equality comparable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ `operator ==` for `std::string` compares the content of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is a `std::string` it already has an operator== defined. It compares the contents of the strings.

If it is a C string (`char*`) the comparison is a pointer comparison that tells us if the pointers points to the same string. You cannot overload this either as it is a built in operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a bunch of operators implemented for `std::string` (compare `std::string` and `const char*` etc.)

If you have a custom type, then you'll need to provide operators for those.